# joomla news site. All news in blog format

Tags: joomla, blogs, joomla1.7

I am trying to build a news website in Joomla 1.7.

I want in the main content to display the latest e.g. 10 news and then using the next button to see the rest and so on.

What kind of module do I need? I did a little search and I am guessing a blog module? 
I cannot find a free blog module. Any ideas?

If that is not the way to go, can anybody suggest any other way?

Thank you!
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things - first, you need to upgrade to 2.5, 1.7 dies at the end of the month.

Next, I would use K2 for what you are describing. It's basically a replacement for the standard Joomla category/articles. It has all the features that a blog component should have plus a lot more if you need it.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/8061

Answer (score 1):

1) UPGRADE to Joomla 2.5.1!

2) Blog format is a Joomla core feature, so no need to install any other 3rd party component!

1. Go to your Joomla backend
2. Manage menu
3. Create a new link (give a name....)
4. Type: Articles / Category Blog

In the right panel :
 1. Coose your category name
 2. In blog layout Options :

> Leading Articles **0**
>   Intro Articles **10**
>   Columns **1** (or 2 as you want)
>   Links **0**

Save and enjoy your blog!

Comment: Thank you Arnaud! It seems I have to use the K2 extension though. Still your info helped me in some other projects!